Can anyone provide an argument against astralphysical dualism that is not reductionist materialist, purely physicalist/supportive of physicalism?
In one of my recent literary works, I have chosen to posit an advance of the concept of dualism, via coining the term astralphysical dualism. This concept requires understandings of three root terms:

Astral: Of, connected with or resembling the stars. Relating to a "supposed" nonphysical "realm" of existence to which various psychic and "paranormal phenomena" are ascribed, and in which the physical human body is said to have a counterpart.

Physical: Relating to the body as opposed to the mind; Relating to things via perception through the senses as opposed to the mind; Relating to physics or the operation of natural forces generally.

Dualism: The use of two irreducible, meaning unable to be reduced or simplified, heterogenous principles that may sometimes be in conflict while other times being complementary. It should be noted, if complementary, we can exercise the true definition of equilibrium which is: "A state in which opposing forces or influences are balanced; A state of physical balance; A calm state of mind."


Now, the definition I have put forth that captures the essence of the prior definitions is as follows:
-Astralphysical Dualism: The acknowledgment of both the immaterial and the material. Astral is in reference to the soul and even the mind independent of physical expression, the immaterial and physical is in reference to the mind manifesting as a physical substance through the physical expression of a person or something other. Dualism simply implies that both the astral and physical combination are indeed an application of the dualistic concept.
If we can accept this definition, we could perhaps acknowledge a state of equilibrium (as mentioned above) that could be disrupted via an individual choosing to adhere to specific philosophies. For example, the reductionist materialist philosophy would scoff at the notion of astral, the metaphysical, being relevant to our existence and daily functions. It would perhaps attempt to take all that is immaterial and define it via purely physical means, which would lead to incorrect interpretations, furthermore, providing the illusion of phenomena. This view would indeed destroy the equilibrium of the material and immaterial expressing itself via existence. Thus, I ask if there is perhaps another argument that is not dependent upon reductionist materialism or even purely physicalist ideology.
Can anyone provide such an argument?

Before we get to arguments against it, what's the argument for it? Evidence? Is there something this satisfactorily explains that isn't explained otherwise?

The argument for it is inclusive of a vast compatibility of concepts, ranging from but not limited to: perception, "extra" sensory perception, soft determinism, free will, consciousness, nature, naturalism, reality, deductive reasoning, metaphysics, and of course what was mentioned via the question itself. The challenge I am putting forth is one that simply asks if one can formulate an argument against a metaphysical stance that supports the immaterial, without using a reductionist materialist, purely physicalist argument.

In regard to evidence, there is a solid amount of evidence available simply by understanding compatibility of the terms themselves, via definitions. If you would like more evidence, there are sources such as the Monroe institute that have done federal work (and continue to do so) on matters that regard the relationship between the immaterial and the material. A prime example of this is the program for the CIA that used remote viewing techniques to understand things on the physical level without solely relying on physical means, such as technology. It implies there is an immaterial...

Detail of existence that is always accessible and even operates on some sort of frequency that is identical if not similar to the physical one we operate at. This could prove that the "veil" between "dimensions" is actually wire thin. I should note that the existence of astralphysical dualism is influenced via psychophysical dualism.  This concept allows for the physical properties of human beings, to be properties of the body, while mental properties of human beings are of the mind or soul. Thus, the mind or soul are wholly distinct from the individuals body.

"A prime example of this is the program for the CIA that used remote viewing techniques " - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Project#:~:text=The%20Stargate%20Project's%20work%20primarily,%22psychic%20headhunter%22%20to%20Maj. -- "The Stargate Project was terminated and declassified in 1995 after a CIA report concluded that it was never useful in any intelligence operation. Information provided by the program was vague and included irrelevant and erroneous data"

At the moment, it doesn't look like this idea is substantially more than wild speculation. It might be fun to think about, but there's not a lot to chew on when it comes to rigorous science or philosophy in my estimation.

While that is what is available on Wikipedia, said project was not the only one that dealt with such things. If you would like more information, research Joseph McMoneagle and his work with remote viewing. He has quite literally been the main source of intel for operations and saved missing persons with such a method. It is not fake, this is proven. The idea itself is not simply wild speculation. I assure you. However, such an assurance goes best with understanding that not all governments are going to be upfront about the validity of such things.

Regardless, the positing of astralphysical dualism does not require a government funded project to be supported. In fact, you can go into prolonged states of meditation, use plant medicines and even study Buddhist philosophy to understand there is an immaterial and a material. The Buddhists simply chose to operate in one field or the other, depending upon personal mantra.

Thus, I still ask, even if you must regard this as purely hypothetical, what is the argument against astralphysical dualism that is not purely physicalist? Keep in mind, a suggestion that we haven't done the physical experiments or studies, is indeed a purely physicalist view.

Consider looking in to Nonduality.
